# Is there a possiblity to write/read from a socket on same port from different class

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, server, tcp

Im having Spring Boot Application for communication between Machines (tcp Clients) and TCP Server (localhost). I am able to communicate with one machine/client, but I cant communicate with 2 or more machines.
Therefore I start my Spring Boot Application:

```
package com.example.workflow;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Runnable serverZyklisch = new ServerZyklisch();
    Runnable serverAzyklisch = new ServerAzyklisch();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      new Thread(serverZyklisch).start();
      new Thread(serverAzyklisch).start();
    }
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }
}
```

There I have different Threads started, so that the clients (for example 10.50.12.174 = Press, 10.50.12.204 = Drill) can connect to TCP Server over Socket Connection.

My ServerAzyklisch class is like this:

```
package com.example.workflow;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerAzyklisch implements Runnable, JavaDelegate {
    int count = 0;
    private final ServerSocket ssocket;
    static String param = StartTCPServersDelegate.parameter;
    HexToByteConverter hexToByteConverter = new HexToByteConverter();
    // 2 TCP Server starten Port 2000, Port 2001
    public ServerAzyklisch(String Pparam) throws IOException {
        ssocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
        param = Pparam;
    }

    public ServerAzyklisch() throws IOException {
        ssocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1];
        System.out.println(param+"Paraaam");
        InputStream in;
        OutputStream out = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        //Thread immer aktiv
        int n = 0;
        while(true){
            try {
                // Wartet auf Socket Verbindung
                System.out.println("Server is listening on port "+ ssocket.getLocalPort());
                socket = ssocket.accept();
                count++;
                System.out.println("Countet clients: "+count);
                socket.setSoLinger(true, 1000);
                System.out.println("Sockeport: "+socket.getLocalPort());
                System.out.println("Connection from " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                //Inputstream
                in = socket.getInputStream();
                //Outputstream
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
                //Datenpuffer deklarieren (anlegen)
                byte []data = new byte[132];
                               
                byte[]Pressen1hexdump110 = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("33333333003d0064000600000004004001c9c78900010000006e0000000000000000000000000001000000000014000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"+param);
                byte[]Pressen2hexdump = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("3333333300400065000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
                byte[]Pressen3hexdump = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("3333333300400065001400000000004001c9c6e900010000006e000000000000000000000000000100000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
                                                
                in.read(buf);
                while (buf[0] != -1) {
                    out.write(Pressen1hexdump110);
                    out.write(Pressen2hexdump);
                    out.write(Pressen3hexdump);
                    }
               
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws IOException {
        
    }
}
```

Now I want to outsource the "while loop" (with out.write) in other Classes to use the connection to Socket like in ServerAzyklisch run method.

Therefore I wrote for example a Class Presse.java

```
package com.example.workflow;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Presse implements JavaDelegate {

    ServerSocket ssocket;
    private HexToByteConverter hexToByteConverter = new HexToByteConverter();
    Socket socket;
    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;

    byte[]Pressen1hexdump110 = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("33333333003d0064000600000004004001c9c78900010000006e00000000000000000000000000010000000000140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005");
    byte[]Pressen2hexdump = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("3333333300400065000a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    byte[]Pressen3hexdump = hexToByteConverter.hexStringToByteArray("3333333300400065001400000000004001c9c6e900010000006e000000000000000000000000000100000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");


    public Presse() throws IOException {
        ssocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
        socket = ssocket.accept();
        //Inputstream
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        //Outputstream
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
    }

    public void sendMessage(InputStream in, OutputStream out, byte[]message) throws IOException {
        out.write(Pressen1hexdump110);
        out.write(Pressen2hexdump);
        out.write(Pressen3hexdump);
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws Exception {
        PostRequestDelegate postRequestDelegate = new PostRequestDelegate();
        postRequestDelegate.post();
    }
}
```

I want to send my 3 messages from this class, like in ServerAzyklisch class. But it throws Error because:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
```

I know this because is I do Socket.accept a second time, but I dont understand how I can achieve this to work. Do I have to close socket connection ? If yes where and with which Java Command ?

Comment: You cannot open a port twice. And i guess closing the ServerSocket in the `ServerAzyklisch` class is breaking other things. So you have to find a way to differentiate which class is supposed to handle the respective incoming connection on the original ServerSocket.

Comment: So, probably I can close ServerSocket in ServerAzyklisch class ? and do a new socket.accept in the other Classes ? Or I have to make my other classes (Bohrer.java, Press.Java) make Runnable ? All Clients are listening to same Server + Port, but I have to handle it different ways, which Machine is sending and the respond would be another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have more than one instances of "Presse" in your program, the very least you'll need to remove `ServerSocket` from it. Instead, you should `accept` the connection from the client somewhere else, and pass the client socket to the `Presse` constructor:

```
public Presse(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = clientSocket;
    //Inputstream
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    //Outputstream
    out = socket.getOutputStream();
}
```

Usually you want to create *only one* `ServerSocket`, and call `accept` on it in a loop. To allow more than one client to connect at a time, communicate with the client in a separate thread. This way the server can go and accept a new connection. Here's a skeleton example of how to use a thread pool for this:

```
int maxClients = 10;
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxClients);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
while (true) {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    threadPool.submit(() -> {
        // Communicate with clientSocket, for example:
        Presse p = new Presse(clientSocket);
        // You'll want to have this code in a separate method
    });
}
```

Comment: So this sounds nice, Ill try it this way. I have to sourround it with try Catch Presse p = new Presse(clientSocket). till now. And after i did Presse p = new Presse(clientSocket) I have to do p.sendMessage(); or ?

Comment: You will need to catch and handle exceptions in any case, I haven't included that in the example code so that you can focus on how the thread pool and the sockets are used. Yes after creating an instance of `Presse` you can use it to send messages. I would suggest you put this code in a separate method.

Comment: So you mean with: I would suggest you put this code in a seperate methode, you mean the "skeleton example of how to use thread pool" ? Or just the b.sendMessages(); ? 

So for example: public void handleThreadPool(){  ...skeleton example }